# jQuery change input text value not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do this

```
$('input').val($('input').val()+"^2");
```

so each input field in the page **(I have only one field)** will have two extra letters ^2

the strange thing is that it only append 2 and ignore the ^ symbol. any idea why this strange behavior occurs?

EDIT:
The problem was that there were another part in the code removes all symbols from the input field once they are inserted. So I changed it to ignore this symbol. Thanks guys.

Comment: You probably have to escape the `^`. Try `&#94;2`.

Comment: do note that when you call `$('input').val()` it will return the value of the **first** input, so your code will set **all** input values to the value of the **first** input with your modification.

Comment: I have only one input as this is a custom control I am working on.

Comment: Can you show the markup of this control? The jQuery line itself is correct, there is no need for any escaping here.

Comment: @MahmoudFayez It would probably still be best to provide context and/or be more specific with your selector. If this is to go on a page with other input elements, it could effect them as well.

Comment: I am implementing an on-screen keyboard for latex. which has only one input element and a set of button elements.

Comment: And these buttons are not <input> elements?

Comment: @WolfgangStengel I am using an already exist keyboard here https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/wiki and I am making tweaks to it to support more advanced latex syntax.

Comment: This sounds like your code is adding the ^2 correctly, but a bunch of JavaScript from this library is messing with it.

Comment: I guess you are right I found a regex expression that prevent ^ symbol  from being added!! and I did modify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for me: [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/PpuGE/).

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
&#94;
```

or escape the carrot:

```
/^
```

It renders as  ^

Comment: This will just put `&#94;` in the text box.  So `abc&#94;2` instead of `abc^2`. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gromer/bHxJ3/1/)

Comment: The jQuery val() function accepts a plain text string, there is no HTML involved here. Also, ^ is not a special character either in HTML nor in a JavaScript string.

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping that using a **backslash \**

```
$('input').val($('input').val()+"\^2");​
```

Or use the Unicode equivalent of the caret

[**CHECK FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/ZrTZA/1/)

Comment: Why would a ^ sign need escaping?

Comment: @WolfgangStengel.. I think I used the wrong words to frame the sentence